# Python - Pandas devuelve caracteres "\n"

Tags: python, json, pandas

Hice una aplicacion que scrapea informacion sobre paginas de propiedades con python & pandas, guardandolo en formato .JSON. El problema es que lo guarda con caracteres adicionales, por ejemplo:

```
"Fecha de publicacion": {
  "1": "Hace 5 dias\n",
 },
"Especificaciones": {
  "1": "55 m² totales\n50 m² cubiertos\n2 Habitaciones\n1 Baño\n",
 }
```

Como puedo evitar que printee los \n?

Comment: Puedes eliminar los `\n` con `cadena = cadena.replace("\n", "")`, `str.rsplit/str.split` (cuando están al inicio o final de la cadena), etc pero posiblemente deberías eliminarlos desde el inicio, cuando obtienes los datos o los cargas en el DataFrame... Para eso haría falta ver tu código.

Comment: Esos `\n` no son basura, sino que representan saltos de línea. Quizás no quieras eliminarlos, según lo que vayas a hacer con esas cadenas. Por ejemplo si haces `print(datos["Especificaciones"]["1"])`, lo que se mostraría serían cuatro líneas. Si no los quieres, deberías reemplazarlos por espacios para evitar que lo que antes eran palabras separadas por un salto de línea, queden pegadas. O podrías hacer un `split("\n")` para separar la cadena en varias, una por línea.